# How to declare a global variable from within a class?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to declare a global variable from within a class like so:

```
class myclass:
    global myvar = 'something'
```

I need it to be accessed outside the class, but I don't want to have to declare it outside the class file. My question is, is this possible? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Why not doing it like this: `global myvar;` and in next line, change it?

Comment: Looks like you wanted something different than what you asked

Comment: F.J answered the question as asked so I +1'd, zigg got the intention (not having to type out myclass.var over and over) and it's supposed to be better practice so I'll point future people with the same question arriving from search to his answer.

Comment: Good. But the word 'declare' is misleading. It can be changed to reflect better module `import`ing practice

Comment: My question was in fact about declaring a global from within the class, but I know now that's not the good-programming way of doing this, see zigg's answer. The question was worded correctly for what I originally wanted to know, I chose a different answer because it was the proper way of doing it despite not being exactly what I asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your question, you specify "outside the main file".  If you didn't mean "outside the class", then this will work to define a module-level variable:

```py
myvar = 'something'

class myclass:
    pass
```

Then you can do, assuming the class and variable definitions are in a module called `mymodule`:

```py
import mymodule

myinstance = myclass()
print(mymodule.myvar)
```

Also, in response to your comment on @phihag's answer, you can access myvar unqualified like so:

```py
from mymodule import myvar

print(myvar)
```

If you want to just access it shorthand from another file while still defining it in the class:

```py
class myclass:
    myvar = 'something'
```

then, in the file where you need to access it, assign a reference in the local namespace:

```py
myvar = myclass.myvar

print(myvar)
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant outside the class. The file that calls the class.

Comment: See edit.  It is best to maintain control over your namespaces bringing in only what you need.  Otherwise, you may end up referring to something you did not intend to, as your program gets larger...

Answer (score 6):

You should really rethink whether or not this is really necessary, it seems like a strange way to structure your program and you should phihag's method which is more correct.

If you decide you still want to do this, here is how you can:

```
>>> class myclass(object):
...     global myvar
...     myvar = 'something'
...
>>> myvar
'something'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the "from mymodule import myvar" zigg suggested. Thanks for answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like

```
# I don't like this hackish way :-S
# Want to declare hackish_global_var = 'something' as global
global_var = globals()
global_var['hackish_global_var'] = 'something'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply assign a property to the class:

```
class myclass(object):
   myvar = 'something'

# alternatively
myclass.myvar = 'else'

# somewhere else ...
print(myclass.myvar)
```

Comment: I understand this works, my question is if setting a global variable is possible to avoid having to type out "myclass." a lot. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: @fryy Possible in theory, but a very bad idea and your reason does **not** justify it. This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @fryy generally using the "global" statement anywhere in python is an indication of bad design (although not always, hence why it exists). Often, people coming from other languages see this as something analogous to what they are used to from some previous language.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question

```
global s
s = 5
```

Will do it.  You will run into problems depending on where in your class you do this though.  Stay away from functions to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Global variable within a class can also be defined as:

```
    class Classname:
       name = 'Myname'

    # To access the variable name in a function inside this class:
    def myfunc(self):
        print(Classname.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increment a global class variable as follows -

```
class Employee():
   num_of_employees = 0

   def __init__(self):
       self.name = ''
       Employee.num_of_employees += 1
```

Here, `num_of_employees` variable will be updated everytime a new class object is created, and it's value will be shared across all the objects